# I have just purchased a canon MG3150

Tags: installation, printer

I have just bought Canon MG3150 printer I am trying to connect with my ipad on connecting instructions it says to press the WSP button on my NETGEAR ADSL2 DG834G this does not exist is there an alternative method

Comment: Can you edit the title so that it indicates you have a issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean WPS ?
(WSP is not something I have ever heard of.)

If your Wifi router or accesspoint doesn't do WPS (check the manual) you will have to configure the printer manually in it's setup menu on the LCD panel.

(Some older printers need to be connected by ethernet wire first.
After that is done you can connect to the web-interface in the printer to configure the printers Wifi. After Wifi has been configured you can take it of the wire and use it via Wifi.
This is pretty rare though, newer printers should all be configurable from the LCD panel.)

Unless the printer-manufacturer is extremely stupid there is always a manual configuration method.